# Create JSONObject from string

Tags: java, arrays, json

I know that this question was already asked, i tried all solutions but nothing works for me.
So i have this json syntax string:

```
{
   tasks: [
      {
         blockId: "startpoint1",
         properties: [ "aaaa"  ]
      },
      {
         blockId: "endpoint2",
         properties: [ "tttttt" ]
      } 
   ]
}
```

I tried to create a `JSONObject` from this String by this way:

```
JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();
try {
    JSONObject json=(JSONObject) parser.parse(req.getParameter(WORKFLOW_DEFINITION_PROPERTIES));
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now i want to loop on the `tasks` array to get every element `blockId`. I tried to do this by casting the `JSONObject` to `JSONArray` like this:

```
JSONArray tasks=(JSONArray) json.get("tasks");
```

but i still enable to loop over `tasks` to get the `blockId's`.
Can you tell me what i made wrong or how to fix this?

Comment: `var obj = JSON.parse(string);`

Comment: I'm in Java no javaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the way you create your JSONObject.

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
//later you can access to your array 
JSONArray tasks=(JSONArray) jObject.get("tasks");
```

Comment: The constructor of `JSONObject` is `JSONObject(map)`, so i can't create a `JSONObject` directly with a `String`

Comment: Thats not true, with the version <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160810</version>
        </dependency> you can create an object from a string.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `getJsonArray` method instead of `get` method to retrieve the array of tasks :

```
JSONArray tasks= json.getJsonArray("tasks");
```

Comment: This method is not included in `org.json.simple.JSONArray` class i use

Answer (score -1):

Do you need this?

```
    var arrayVariable=[
      {
         blockId: "startpoint1",
         properties: [ "aaaa"  ]
      },
      {
         blockId: "endpoint2",
         properties: [ "tttttt" ]
      } 
   ]

    arrayVariable.map(function(d){
       return d.blockId
       });
```

Out put you will get all you blockId as

```
     ["startpoint1", "endpoint2"]
```

Comment: No, my json string is created dynamically from an UI diagram so, i can't create it statically like you done

Comment: So,Convert you JSON string to JSON Object using JSON.parse(JSONstring) and then use my above method it will work